# Take first first column from 1.csv and find in second 2.csv

Tags: bash, shell

I want to read two csv files (`a.csv` and `b.csv`) and write a new csv file `new.csv` with a status of each column. I want to do that with a shell script.

**A.csv**:

```
Inputfile_name,Date
abc.csv,2018/11/26  16.38.54 
bbc.csv,2018/11/26  15.28.11
```

**B.csv**:

```
Outputfile_name,Date
abc_SUCCESS.csv,2018/11/26  17.20.11
bbc_FAIL.csv,2018/11/26  16.28.11
```

**new.csv**:

```
Inputfile_name,Date,Outputfile_name,Date,Status
abc.csv,2018/11/26  16.38.54,abc_SUCCESS.csv,2018/11/26  17.20.11,SUCCESS
bbc.csv,2018/11/26  15.28.11,bbc_FAIL.csv,2018/11/26  16.28.11,FAIL
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: I'd say that is too broad. You're requesting code without showing any attempts from your side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so?

```
$ paste -d, A.csv B.csv | sed -e 's/\(SUCCESS\|FAIL\).*/&,\1/'
Inputfile_name,Date,Outputfile_name,Date
abc.csv,2018/11/26 16.38.54,abc_SUCCESS.csv,2018/11/26 17.20.11,SUCCESS
bbc.csv,2018/11/26 15.28.11,bbc_FAIL.csv,2018/11/26 16.28.11,FAIL
```

[`paste`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paste_(Unix)) can concatenate the contents of two files linewise. And with `sed` you can do a search+replace operation for adding `SUCCESS` or `FAIL` at the end of each line.

Comment: This assumes that files are ordered and each input file name in the first csv file has a corresponding output file name in the second file.

Comment: @user1376290 Sort them first: `sort -t"," -k2,2.12 -k1 file`.

Comment: **Thanks it is working, but header is coming in last line**

abc.csv,2018/11/26  16.38.54 ,abc_SUCCESS.csv,2018/11/26  17.20.11,SUCCESS

abc.csv,2018/11/26  15.28.11,bbc_FAIL.csv,2018/11/26  16.28.11,FAIL

Inputfile_name,Date,Outputfile_name,Date


I have aslo tried below command but it is getting only header not the data.


'paste -d,  AA.csv BB.csv | sed -n '1p' | sed -e 's/\(SUCCESS\|FAIL\).*/&,\1/' >>new.csv'

Comment: @user1376290 Handle the header separately, e. g. extract with `head -1 file` and process the rest with `tail -n+2 file`.